# Passing argv from route into a script in Node without single quotes

Tags: node.js, argv

I have a project with a landing page which uploads a file into the server; then select some parameters including the uploaded filename and pass them to a script to deploy that file to another server.
I have trouble into passing the filename as parameter for the script. I managed with, inside the upload.js route

```
var fileName = util.inspect(files.upload.name);
var fileSize = util.inspect(files.upload.size);
process.argv = fileName;
```

And then calling in deploy.js route

```
var env = Object.create(process.env);
env.package = process.argv;
```

so if I try to load a file called try.sql, it passes into the argv array as 'try.sql'. How can I pass it to the script without single quotes?

The script now is very simple:

```
cp /c/users/alex.buaiscia/Documents/Developing/node/uploads/$package /c/users/alex.buaiscia/Documents/Developing/
```

so for clarifying, it returns:

```
stderr: cp: cannot stat "/c/users/alex.buaiscia/Documents/Developing/node/uploads/'try.sql'"
```

Whole project is on public github
https://github.com/buaiscia/newPKI

Thanks!

---update with current solution----

```
///// PASSING ARGUMENT FILENAME TO SCRIPT
    var env = Object.create(process.env);
    env.package = process.argv;

    var array1 = env.package;

    console.log(array1.slice(1, -1));
    var array2 = array1.slice(1, -1);


    var command = 'sh c:/users/alex.buaiscia/Documents/Developing/node/scripts/testdeploy.sh ' + array2 + ' >> log.txt'
    console.log(command);
 exec(command, { env: env }, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('done')
        console.log('stdout:', stdout);
        console.log('stderr:', stderr);
    });
```

+ testdeploy.sh

```
echo $(date) 'prova deployment'
echo $(date) $1
cp /c/users/alex.buaiscia/Documents/Developing/node/uploads/$1 /c/users/alex.buaiscia/Documents/Developing/node/
```

Comment: removing quotes will trouble you when you have spaces in your file name or any other argument. A good way could be removing quotes while you are using env.package.

Comment: thanks, but how? I could do it through a loop but I'll have to pass it back to the argv returning the problem...

Comment: Actually it worked! although in some rusty way
I assigned a new variable to the env var and then sliced the quotes
var array1 = env.package;
var array2 = array1.slice(1, -1);
and passed the array2 as parameter for the script instead of argument. 
Works fine, thanks!

Comment: are you running this in cli? "cp /c/users/alex.buaiscia/Documents/Developing/node/uploads/$package /c/users/alex.buaiscia/Documents/Developing/"

Comment: sorry we replied at the same time, do you have some more elegant solution than what I posted here above?

Comment: can you show me the whole code?

Comment: I've updated the last part of the question with the considered part of deploy.js and the script. There's some redundancy (I know I can call the cp from the exec) as it's just a test, the real script is more complex.

Comment: @Alex how are you invoking the node code? you may be passing the argument already quoted in `process.argv`